# XML SQL Server querying to retrieve attribute value and tag text value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm new to querying XML in SQL Server, this is not one of my daily tasks, I'm helping a colleague. For example I have the following XML stored on a column in SQL:

How can I retrieve two columns, one having the id value and the other one, the value from the next inside tag (eg.:2109 and 0 from `<Bool>0</Bool>`)

Desired output:

```
id  value
2109    0
341     2
342     10
2196    753064REPJ1
1283    2
1293    0_Imprumutat
```

Thx!

```
<Item id="645" flags="769">
  <Row>
    <Item id="2109" flags="257">
      <Bool>0</Bool>
    </Item>
    <Item id="341" flags="257">
      <Str>2</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="342" flags="257">
      <Str>10</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2196" flags="257">
      <Str>753064REPJ1</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1283" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Str>2</Str>
      </Row>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1293" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Str>0_Imprumutat</Str>
      </Row>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1251" flags="257">
      <Str>2079759</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2101" flags="257">
      <Dbl>500000</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="343" flags="257">
      <Str>2</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2065" flags="257">
      <Dbl>1000000</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2098" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2102" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2100" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2099" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="359" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="361" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="347" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2346" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1912" flags="513">
      <Str>1234</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2219" flags="513">
      <Str>1234</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="356" flags="513">
      <Int>1999</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2218" flags="513">
      <Str>123</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2220" flags="513">
      <Str>123</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2702" flags="513">
      <Date>2016-10-02Z</Date>
    </Item>
    <Item id="377" flags="513">
      <Int>1</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1218" flags="513">
      <Int>0</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1219" flags="513">
      <Int>0</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1596" flags="513">
      <Int>2</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="351" flags="513">
      <Str>Adresa</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="352" flags="513">
      <Str>B3</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="353" flags="513">
      <Str>LOc</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="354" flags="513">
      <Int>1</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="355" flags="513">
      <Str>jfdkls</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1288" flags="513">
      <Int>3</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="368" flags="513">
      <Int>9</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1887" flags="513">
      <Str>Realtech Services SRL</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="370" flags="513">
      <Date>2015-10-02Z</Date>
    </Item>
    <Item id="375" flags="513">
      <Int>2</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="371" flags="513">
      <Str>Asirom</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="372" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="373" flags="513">
      <Str>RON</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="374" flags="513">
      <Date>2016-01-05Z</Date>
    </Item>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Item id="2109" flags="257">
      <Bool>0</Bool>
    </Item>
    <Item id="341" flags="257">
      <Str>1</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="342" flags="257">
      <Str>1</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2196" flags="257">
      <Str>753064REPF2</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1283" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Str>2</Str>
      </Row>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1293" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Str>0_Imprumutat</Str>
      </Row>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1251" flags="257">
      <Str>2079759</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2101" flags="257">
      <Dbl>500000</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="343" flags="257">
      <Str>1</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2065" flags="257">
      <Dbl>1000000</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2098" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2102" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2100" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2099" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="347" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2346" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1912" flags="513">
      <Str>123</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2219" flags="513">
      <Str>1236</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="356" flags="513">
      <Int>1999</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2218" flags="513">
      <Str>123</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2702" flags="513">
      <Date>2016-01-02Z</Date>
    </Item>
    <Item id="377" flags="513">
      <Int>1</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1218" flags="513">
      <Int>0</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1219" flags="513">
      <Int>0</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1596" flags="513">
      <Int>2</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="351" flags="513">
      <Str>jgfkdl</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="352" flags="513">
      <Str>B3</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="353" flags="513">
      <Str>gfdgfd</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="354" flags="513">
      <Int>1</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="355" flags="513">
      <Str>gfdgfd</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="357" flags="513">
      <Int>9</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1288" flags="513">
      <Int>3</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="368" flags="513">
      <Int>9</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1887" flags="513">
      <Str>Euroeval SRL</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="370" flags="513">
      <Date>2015-09-02Z</Date>
    </Item>
    <Item id="375" flags="513">
      <Int>2</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="371" flags="513">
      <Str>Allianz-Tiriac</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="372" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="373" flags="513">
      <Str>RON</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="374" flags="513">
      <Date>2017-10-28Z</Date>
    </Item>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Item id="2109" flags="257">
      <Bool>0</Bool>
    </Item>
    <Item id="341" flags="257">
      <Str>1</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="342" flags="769">
      <Str>14</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2196" flags="257">
      <Str>753064REPF3</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1283" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Str>2</Str>
      </Row>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1293" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Str>0_Imprumutat</Str>
      </Row>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1251" flags="257">
      <Str>2079759</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2101" flags="257">
      <Dbl>500000</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="343" flags="257">
      <Str>1</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2065" flags="257">
      <Dbl>1000000</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2100" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2099" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2102" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2098" flags="257">
      <Dbl>0</Dbl>
    </Item>
    <Item id="359" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="361" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="347" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2346" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1912" flags="513">
      <Str>12346</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2219" flags="513">
      <Str>54</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="356" flags="513">
      <Int>1999</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2218" flags="513">
      <Str>123</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2220" flags="513">
      <Str>123</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2702" flags="513">
      <Date>2016-10-02Z</Date>
    </Item>
    <Item id="377" flags="513">
      <Int>1</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1218" flags="513">
      <Int>0</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1219" flags="513">
      <Int>0</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1596" flags="513">
      <Int>2</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="351" flags="513">
      <Str>iuyiy</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="352" flags="513">
      <Str>B2</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="353" flags="513">
      <Str>kjhlhj</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="354" flags="513">
      <Int>1</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="355" flags="513">
      <Str>lkjhljh</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="357" flags="513">
      <Int>9</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1288" flags="513">
      <Int>1</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="368" flags="513">
      <Int>9</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="1887" flags="513">
      <Str>Euroeval SRL</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="370" flags="513">
      <Date>2016-06-02Z</Date>
    </Item>
    <Item id="375" flags="513">
      <Int>2</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="371" flags="513">
      <Str>Uniqa</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="372" flags="513">
      <Int>1000000</Int>
    </Item>
    <Item id="373" flags="513">
      <Str>RON</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="374" flags="513">
      <Date>2016-02-21Z</Date>
    </Item>
  </Row>
</Item>
```

Comment: is you want always <Bool>0</Bool> value with his Item Id ??

Comment: it would be great if you post here some sample output what you want

Answer (score 2):

You need to use XQuery, `outer apply` and give path to your target node.

**Final Query**

```
SELECT  n.a.value('@id','int') as id,n.a.value('(Bool)[1]','bit')
from xmldata x
        outer apply x.data.nodes('Item/Row/Item')as n(a)
where n.a.value('(Bool)[1]','varchar(max)') is not null
```

**Explanation:**

After navigating to desired node, use `n.a.value('@Attribute','datatype')` syntax to fetch required attribute,`n.a.value('(ElementName)[1]','datatype')` syntax to fetch element value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sql:variable()` or `sql:column()` (within an XPATH expression). I declared an XML-variable "@x" and set it to the XML given above.

With this you get exactly what you want:

```
DECLARE @outerID INT=645;
DECLARE @innerID INT=2109;

SELECT @x.value('(/Item[@id=sql:variable("@outerID")]/Row[1]/Item[@id=sql:variable("@innerID")]/Bool)[1]','bit')
```

If you need it for all rows-nodes in your XML you can go like this:

```
DECLARE @id INT=2109;
SELECT Item.OneRow.value('(*[@id=sql:variable("@id")])[1]','bit')
FROM @x.nodes('/Item/Row') AS Item(OneRow)
```

This statement will extract all ids, first child's name and value together with ther Row-number:

```
;WITH TheRows AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowInx
          ,AllRows.OneRow.query('.') AS RowXML
    FROM @x.nodes('/Item/Row') AS AllRows(OneRow) 
)
SELECT RowInx
      ,AllRowItems.OneItem.value('@id','int') AS id
      ,AllRowItems.OneItem.value('@flags','int') AS flags
      ,AllRowItems.OneItem.query('fn:local-name(./*[1])') AS elementName
      ,AllRowItems.OneItem.value('(./*)[1]','varchar(max)') AS elementValue
FROM TheRows
CROSS APPLY RowXML.nodes('/Row/Item') AS AllRowItems(OneItem)
```